# Корректно ли составлена программа для нахождения наибольшего общего делителя?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void)
{
    int a=25;
    int b=45;

    while (a!=0 && b!=0)
        if (a>b)
            a=a%b;
        else 
            b=b%a;
        printf ("%d,%d",a+b);
        return 0; 
}
```

Comment: А в чем проблема проверить самому?

Comment: Только отступы поправить надо.

Answer (score 2):

Корректно, но можно проще:

```
unsigned gcd(unsigned a, unsigned b)
  {
  if(!b)
    return a | !a;

  while(true) 
    {
    if(!(a%=b))   return b;
    if(!(b%=a))   return a;
    }
  }
```